# Interjecting $sce into a controller

Tags: angularjs

I have some HTML that is coming in a string and need the HTML to be rendered. Looking at using the ng-bind-html. That requires $sce to be injected into the controller. All of the example that I can fine have the controller set up like this.

```
angular.module('mySceApp', ['ngSanitize'])
.controller('MyController', ['$sce'] ...
```

But I have my controllers set up like this

```
app.component('myComponent', {
        templateUrl: '../template.html',
        controller: myController,
```

Where myController is a separate js file.

Any idea how I am supposed to do this with my setup?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your separate js file there  should be function that reference the controller. just pass it as parameter to that function like this

```
function myController($sce){

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!